# Rails Controllers - Consolidate or Not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, structure

I have an app where there are multiple ways to engage different resources. For example:

**For Projects:**

- Customers can create, view, edit and cancel their projects
- Admins can view, edit and make other changes (such as changing the
  status and editing hidden fields)
- Suppliers can view projects and add previous projects with other
  customers to their portfolio

For directory structure, I had intended to create these under 3 separate controllers namely: “customers/projects”, “admins/projects” and “suppliers/projects”. But I’m now thinking - should I rather combine these all and rather put conditional logic in the controller to change what each type of user can see or do?

I am worried about authorization ( I know I could use Pundit to solve this?) but also about over complicating the one controller! What is best practice in a scenario like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opted to keep them separate, the main reason was around the views. While you can consolidate with one controller for a resource, and manage authorization with CanCanCan or Pundit, the views for each will be numerous and unique(Eg: a different index action, different project_params based on the respective create and update actions). Putting this all in one controller would be  dog show!